# Flutter http [GET][200] empty for exact API

Tags: api, flutter, http

After coming back to an old project (switched to Mac from Win) I can't run it as http to https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/ returns empty with status code 200. I've tried other API's and it does work fine with the same code. I tried Dio package, results are the same.

Code piece for a call.

```
static const baseUrl = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api';

Future<BootstrapData> getBootstrapData() async {
  var response = await http.get('$baseUrl/bootstrap-static/');
  return BootstrapData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

Also, to mention I've re-installed the app from phone (as it was failing due to build from Win) and upgraded flutter version (tried downgrading too).

I can access the url via browser or Postman. Any idea what might cause this behaviour? Could it be any of environment configurations fault? I am out of ideas...

**EDIT:**
I am not sure if this is of any help, but the response header via my app (It's different than any of Postman or directly browser request headers):

```
{ 
  x-timer: S1604428734.150394,VS0,VE0, 
  x-served-by: cache-bma1625-BMA, 
  connection: close, 
  accept-ranges: bytes, 
  date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 18:38:54 GMT, 
  content-length: 0, 
  via: 1.1 varnish, 
  retry-after: 0, 
  content-type: application/json, 
  x-cache-hits: 0, 
  x-cache: MISS, 
  server: Varnish
}
```

Comment: Did you use a template string in http.get? Looks like a normal quote

Answer (score 0):

Try making the Future a type of HTTP response and then once the response is completed make that of type bootstrapdata

Comment: Same effect, unfortunately